# Hibernate Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 6.2.7 and I'm getting and Exception with this class mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Departamento")
public class Departamento implements Modelo<Departamento>{
    private IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private StringProperty nombre = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    public Departamento() {
        
    }
    
    public Departamento(Departamento departamento) {
        if(departamento != null) {
            setId(departamento.getId());
            setNombre(departamento.getNombre());
        }
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", type = IncrementGenerator.class)
    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }
    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }
    @Column(name="nombre")
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre.get();
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre.set(nombre);
    }
    public StringProperty nombreProperty() {
        return nombre;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getNombre();
    }   
    @Transient
    public String getSomethingNotInDB() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

When running the application this Exception is thrown:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.processBootEntities(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.buildSessionFactory(MetadataImpl.java:205)
    at com.bachiller.calendario/com.bachiller.calendario.modules.CalendarioModule.<init>(CalendarioModule.java:74)
    at com.bachiller.calendario/com.bachiller.calendario.App.start(App.java:29)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field public static volatile java.util.concurrent.Callable com.bachiller.calendario.model.Departamento$HibernateAccessOptimizer$aSJtlre5.invocationTarget$eaok5k0 accessible: module com.bachiller.calendario does not "exports com.bachiller.calendario.model" to unnamed module @14a2f921
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.privilege.SetAccessibleAction.run(SetAccessibleAction.java:49)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.privilege.SetAccessibleAction.run(SetAccessibleAction.java:28)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.LoadedTypeInitializer$ForStaticField.doPrivileged(LoadedTypeInitializer.java)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.LoadedTypeInitializer$ForStaticField.onLoad(LoadedTypeInitializer.java:168)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.LoadedTypeInitializer$Compound.onLoad(LoadedTypeInitializer.java:234)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:103)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:6317)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.load(ByteBuddyState.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl.getReflectionOptimizer(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.resolveReflectionOptimizer(EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.<init>(EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.ManagedTypeRepresentationResolverStandard.resolveStrategy(ManagedTypeRepresentationResolverStandard.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:140)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.7.Final/org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:92)
    ... 18 more
Exception running application com.bachiller.calendario.App
```

I tried to remove @Transient annotation, and the constructor with arguments but it seems they are not the problem.
Any idea on why is this happening and how to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: This model class is incomplete, I guess. Somwhere a static volatile field was defined. Please edit question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: It is not incomplete. The only thing that changes from my real class is that I override toString method (I edited the  sample code to add it) and that getSomethingNotInDB() has another name and another return content. But I tried to run the Application without both methods and without the constructor with arguments, and the same exception is thrown.

Comment: What's more, I tried a simplifier class with only id field (no constructor declared, no other fields and methods) and the same exception is thrown